# Código no manda datos a base de datos

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

El problema radica a la hora de guardar en el Form, este no envía los datos. Al clickear guardar me manda a una página en blanco, y no hace nada.

Aquí los códigos

//Controlador home

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');





class Home extends CI_Controller {


public function index() 
{
    // Loading the model where the queries are executed
    $this->load->model('accounts');
    $this->load->library('javascript');


    $Cuentas = $this->accounts->getAllAccountInfo();


    $data =  array('Cuentas' => $Cuentas);
    $this->load->view('admin/index', $data);

}
public function demo()
{
    echo "Hola soy German";
}

 public function guardarDatos()
{
//recoger datos del formulario
/*Ejemplo para recoger datos del formulario. 
Ya que estas enviando datos por post, para recojer los datos del mismo se hace de la siguiente manera.
*/

$first = $this->input->post('first');  //donde el parametro que envias a la funcion post es el name del input en tu form. Y de la misma manera tienes que hacer con los inputs restantes.

//llamar método del modelo para guardar datos
$arreglo_datos = array('first'=>$first);
$this->accounts->saveData($arreglo_datos);
}

}
```

//Controlador Model

```
<?php

class Accounts extends CI_Model {

    //$table_name = 'accounts'; // Main table name where the queries going to run

    public function __construct()
    {
            // Call the CI_Model constructor
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();


    }


    /**
     * This method returns the account information from all users on the database
     * @return Array()
     */
    public function getAllAccountInfo() {
        $query = $this->db->select('cuenta, nombre, buscar, pago, monto, fecha, banco, interes, concepto, cuota, credito, debito')->get('accounts')->result_array();
        return $query;
    }
     public function saveData($arreglo_de_datos_formulario)
{
  if(!$this->db->insert("accounts",$arreglo_de_datos_formulario)){
   return $this->db->error();
  }

  }

    ?>
```

//Controlador que carga la vista

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

/**
 * Index Page for this controller.
 *
 * Maps to the following URL
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
 *  - or -  
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
 *  - or -
 * Since this controller is set as the default controller in 
 * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
 *
 * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
 * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
 * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('welcome');
}
}
```

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */

//Formulario

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Cuentas por Cobrar</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo site_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css');?>" >
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/bootstrap.js');?>"></script>


  <script src="http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'>

```
<style type="text/css">
    #success_message{ display: none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
<form class="well form-horizontal" action="<?php echo site_url('home/guardarDatos');?>" method="POST"  id="contact_form">
<fieldset>




 <legend>Cuentas por Pagar</legend>



 <div class="form-group">
```

Cuenta

Nombres

```
   <div class="form-group">
```

Fecha

Banco  
    
    
        
  
    
  



  Monto  
    
    
        
  
    
  





  Cuota  
    
    
        
  
    
  


 
  Pago
    
    
        
    
      Seleccionar Tipo de Pago
      Efectivo
      Tarjeta de Crédito
      Tarjeta de Débito
      Cheque

    
  




  Interés  
    
    
        
  
    




  Comentario
    
    
        
            
  
  




Success  Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.




  
  
    Guardar

Cuenta
                    Nombres
          Monto
          Fecha
                    Pago
                    Banco
          Cuota
          Interés

```
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</div>

  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
        // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            first_name: {
                validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                        min: 2,
                    },
                        notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Por favor pon tu nombre'
                    }
                }
            },
             last_name: {
                validators: {
                     stringLength: {
                        min: 2,
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Por favor pon tu apellido'
                    }
                }
            },
            email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {

                    },
                    emailAddress: {

                    }
                }
            },
            phone: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Por favor ponga el nombre del banco'
                    },
                    phone: {


                    }
                }
            },
            address: {
                validators: {
                     stringLength: {
                        min: 8,
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Inserte un Concepto'
                    }
                }
            },
            city: {
                validators: {
                     stringLength: {
                        min: 4,
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please supply your city'
                    }
                }
            },
            state: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Ponga el valor de la cuota'
                    }
                }
            },
            zip: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Ponga el valor del interés'
                    },
                    zipCode: {

                    }
                }
            },
            comment: {
                validators: {
                      stringLength: {
                        min: 10,
                        max: 200,
                        message:'Por favor ponga un comentario entre 10 y 200 caracteres'
                    },
                    notEmpty: {

                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
            $('#success_message').slideDown({ opacity: "show" }, "slow") // Do something ...
                $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();

            // Prevent form submission
            e.preventDefault();

            // Get the form instance
            var $form = $(e.target);

            // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
            var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

            // Use Ajax to submit form data
            $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }, 'json');
        });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

En mi experiencia previa: una página en blanco suele ocurrir porque hay algún error en el código que se ejecuta en el servidor, que hace que termine la ejecución antes de que se muestre nada y por eso se ve todo en blanco.

Mi primera recomendación sería que mostrases todos los errores. Esto se puede hacer incluyendo esto al principio del fichero PHP:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Ahora, estaba formateando el código que compartes porque la indentación y uso de los espacios en blanco me hacía difícil entender lo que había (segunda recomendación: un código limpio es más fácil de mantener y depurar que un código desordenado), y me encontré con que en el controlador Model te falta un cierre de llaves, lo que hará que falle y acabará mostrándote una página en blanco si no estás mostrando errores con el método mostrado arriba.

El error está en estas líneas:

```
<?php

class Accounts extends CI_Model {

// [...el resto del código no es relevante para mostrar el problema...]

     public function saveData($arreglo_de_datos_formulario)
{
  if(!$this->db->insert("accounts",$arreglo_de_datos_formulario)){
   return $this->db->error();
  }

  }

    ?>
```

Y se verá más claro si damos un formato apropiado al código:

```
<?php

class Accounts extends CI_Model {

    // [...el resto del código no es relevante para mostrar el problema...]

    public function saveData($arreglo_de_datos_formulario)
    {
        if(!$this->db->insert("accounts",$arreglo_de_datos_formulario)){
           return $this->db->error();
        }
    }

// aquí falta la llave de cierre } para la clase!

?>
```

Como ves, has dejado la clase sin cerrar. Ese es uno de los problemas (puede haber más) que causan que se muestre una página en blanco y no se guarde nada. Prueba a corregirlo e inténtalo de nuevo a ver los resultados.